# how to open specific screen from a url in react native

Tags: react-native

i have a pyment gateway in my app and i'm using "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn" to go to payment website. how can i go to app dashboard on successful payment? I've been trying to implement it with deep linking but couldn't do it. On successful payment browser open URL like this :http://**8.*1.**9.**/successpage:

This is my intent in manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> <data android:scheme="stylon"/> <data android:scheme="https" android:host="**8.*1.**9.**/" /> <data android:scheme="http" android:host="**8.*1.**9.**/" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

this is my navigation container:

```
<NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef} linking={prefixes: ['stylon://', 'http://**8.*1.**9.**/'],}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The react-navigation's official documentation has an entry for this feature with deep-linking. Take a look [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links#mapping-path-to-route-names)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways by which you can navigate by url

1. By Linking
2. By webView